# django ModelManager inheritance

Tags: django, django-models

How do I inherit a ModelManager?

```
class Content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Name des Blogs')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    active = ContentActiveManager()

class ContentActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ContentActiveManager,self).get_query_set().filter(activated=True,show=True)

class BlogCatalog(Content):
    frequency = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2, choices=make_index_based_tuple(l=FREQUENCY), verbose_name='Frequenz',)



blog = BlogCatalog.active.get(pk=1)
```

`blog` is now obviously a Content object.
If I type Catalog.active.get(pk=1) I want a Content object but
If I type BlogCatalog.active.get(pk=1) I want a BlogCatalog object.

How do I achieve this without being redundant?

Answer (score 2):

Django only allows Manager inheritance from an abstract base class. To use the same manager as a non-ABC, you have to declare it explicitly.

Check out the [django docs on custom managers and inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance).

Basically, just do this:

```
class BlogCatalog(Content):
    frequency = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2, choices=make_index_based_tuple(l=FREQUENCY), verbose_name='Frequenz',)
    active = ContentActiveManager()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, that helped thank you.
The problem is that I always think my idea can't be the smartest way to approach this problem :-/.
I thought of just giving the BlogCatalog an ContentActiveManager but I wasn't sure whether this was considered 'good code'.
Thank you for the help :).

Comment: yep, this is the way the django devs have set things up. So as long as Content isn't an ABC this is considered the "right" way to do things ;-)

Answer (score 0):

the only way I figured out:

```
class Content:

    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super_new = super(Content, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        cls.add_to_class('active', ContentActiveManager())
        return super_new
```